# InstallShield maintenance mode not running

Tags: windows-installer, conditional-statements, installshield, maintenance-mode

I have a InstallShield Basic MSI project. It installs correctly, but when I run Setup.exe on a machine where my program is already installed, the Maintenance Mode dialog doesn't show. Instead, the Setup Resume dialog shows.

Conditions for Maintenance Welcome:

`Installed and Not RESUME and NOT Preselected and NOT Patch`

Conditions for Setup Resume:

`Installed and (RESUME or Preselected) and NOT Patch and INSTALL_TYPE~<>'upgrade'`

Setup Resume is right above Maintenance Welcome in the UI sequence.

Checking the log, I see that the Preselected property is set to 1 at the beginning of installation, which is why I believe Maintenance Welcome is failing. Also in the log, it says `(condition is false)` for the Maintenance Welcome dialog.

However, I have no clue as to why it is being set to 1 (I'm new to InstallShield). Why is it being set to 1, and how can the Maintenance Welcome dialog be shown instead of Setup Resume in my scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

the [reference for Preselect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that its set when either the installation is resumed or you set a specific property via command line.

is this the case for you installation?

maybe it wasn't successful in the first place?